# Boolean functions removed faces, is there a relatively quick way to fix this?

Tags: modifiers, 3d-printing

I've been working a tube chassis model to 3D print. I used the boolean union function to join the tubes together into one object, hoping it would be watertight and printable without too many issues to fix. I realized once everything was connected and saved that several faces are missing, and the joints between "tubes" are not particularly clean. Based on my non-manifold selection, it would probably about as long to find and fix each problem as it did to make it. Is there anything that might be able to make it easier/quicker? Or at least a better way to remake this that would result in less issues to fix? I'm fairly new to blender yet and I'm not real familiar with all of its features yet. Thanks in advance.

Here's my .blend file, hopefully the link works: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=48820

Answer (score 1):

Blender can [select non-manifold edges](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/advanced.html#select-all-by-traits) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>. The [mesh analysis](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/mesh_analysis.html) display options can also be useful for 3D printing.

You will find enabling the [3D Print Toolbox](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/PrintToolbox) addon will be helpful. Click the Check all button to see how many locations have issues. While there is a Make Manifold button, be careful to check that the automated process doesn't add unwanted faces.

[image: 3D print toolbox]

If you are in edit mode each item listed will be a button that will select the relevant areas.

[image: select items]

Comment: I'm aware of this feature, it's how I found that it was non-manifold in the first place. When I select "make manifold", most of the object is simply deleted. I do appreciate you answering though

Comment: The "Make Manifold" button can give bad results, but using the non-manifold edge button under results is a quick way to select what needs fixing so they are easy to find and it quickly tells you when you are done.